# Floating 4 elements left and right in an order

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

I am having an issue while setting up navigation in an order. I have 4 div tags and it should be in an order as left, right, right, left. so I expect my navigation should look like this
 [image: expectation]

I am having issue with float right. I have tried this

```css
.footer {

}

li {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background-color: orange;
}

.two {

}

.copy {
  background-color: blue;
}

.two, .three {
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="one" >
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100" alt="footer" />
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <ul>
          <li>privacy</li>
          <li>terms and conditions</li>
          <li>contact us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="three">
        <ul>
          <li>instagram</li>
          <li>facebook</li>
          <li>twitter</li>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="copy">
        &copy; 2020 mysite.com
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

somehow float is not keeping my unordered list to the top. I have searched through the stackoverflow. but I couldn't find any answer. It will be more helpful if I get this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no change div structure, just using `display:gird`

```css
.footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

li {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

.two {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.three {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.two, .three {
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: right;
}

.copy {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="one" >
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100" alt="footer" />
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <ul>
          <li>privacy</li>
          <li>terms and conditions</li>
          <li>contact us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="three">
        <ul>
          <li>instagram</li>
          <li>facebook</li>
          <li>twitter</li>
      </div>
      <div class="copy">
        &copy; 2020 mysite.com
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @rangerz. but i would like to keep the 4 divs as it is because I need to change the position of the copyright text at the last for mobile devices.

Comment: @WBGUY001 I fixed it.